# Custom field value doesn't get saved

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, plugin-feedme

I have the following code:

```
$fieldHandle = 'contentLead';

$entryTitle = $event->element;
$entryQuery = \craft\elements\Entry::find();

$entries = $entryQuery->title($entryTitle)->limit(1);

foreach ($entries->all() as $entry) {
    $entry->setFieldValue($fieldHandle, 'hello');

    Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry, false, true);
}
```

Comment: After saving the element, does `$entry->getErrors()` return anything?

Comment: Sorry for disappearing, I worked around this issue (forked the Guest Entries plugin). Using the code above in a different case worked perfectly, thanks!